# Codeigniter PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object when call $this->config->item(‘config_item’)

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->config->item('config_item')
```

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Anyone knows how to fix this kind of problem? Or anyone ever been had same stuff?

The error happens on every call of config item rather in libraries classes (e.g. `form_validation` class) or in application controller.

If I `print_r($this->config)` it shows array of config content.

Comment: `$this->config->site_url();` generates the same error?

Comment: What about... print_r($this->config->item('log_date_format')); ? What's the name of the setting item your trying to load? is it defined in the config.php file in the application/config folder?

Comment: yes $this->config->site_url(); generates same error @AlfonsoRubalcava

Comment: @BTellez i'm going to use form_validation library. but when i load form_validation it generates error caused by $this->CI->config->item error on form->validation library. so every library contains function to call config item generates error

Comment: anyone? i guess this caused by wrong config or something i'm not to familiar to CI. but one thing for sure i cant just bypass by changing $this->config->item('blablabla') to $this->config['blablabla'] cause that is not the answer i'm looking for

Comment: If you [edit] your post with the *entire* code of one of the libraries or controllers that generates this error, it would help a lot.

Comment: Please add the output of print_r($this->config) to your post

Comment: never mind... i've found the solusition.. thank you all.. i'm using too much third party classes and API so there's some conflict